# cookies disable error in ios safari while loading Iframe in other websites

Tags: ios, swift, web, safari

I am facing cookies disable error while loading Iframe in third party website.Its my application page that is being loaded in an Iframe on other website and though cookies are being enabled safari reports error like "

> please enable cookies or click here or Press ESC to reload the page".

Any type of help will be highly appreciated..!!